# Custom Profile URL like <site url>/<username> Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the user's profile by **www.siteurl.com/user/username instead of www.siteurl.com/user?name=username**

This is perfectly working in localhost, but not in **live server
It just give a 404 Page Not Found, But in localhost it directs to requested url**. How can I do this in live server?

This is my code

In `config.php` enabled the hooks

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Then create a hooks.php adding following code in application->config

```
$hook=array(
        'pre_system' => array(
                array(
                        'class'    => 'Userlookup',
                        'function' => 'check_uri',
                        'filename' => 'Userlookup.php',
                        'filepath' => 'hooks',
                        'params'   => NULL,
                ),
        ),
);
```

Then, in application-> hooks create Userlookup.php it contains,

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or die('No direct script access allowed');

class Userlookup{

    protected $uri_username;
    protected $connection_method;

    protected $hostname;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $database;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Configure database connection
        include(APPPATH.'config/database'.EXT);
        $this->hostname = $db[$active_group]['hostname'];
        $this->username = $db[$active_group]['username'];
        $this->password = $db[$active_group]['password'];
        $this->database = $db[$active_group]['database'];

   }

    public function check_uri()
    {
         // First, we need get the uri segment to inspect
         $request_uri = explode('/',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));    //$request_uri[0] == username
         $this->uri_username = array_shift($request_uri);                   //string 'socialsite' (length=10)
         $connection_router = array_shift($request_uri);
         $this->connection_method = empty($connection_router) ? 'index' : $connection_router;
         // Connect to database, and check the user table
         mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password) AND mysql_select_db($this->database);
         $res = mysql_query("SELECT user_Id FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name='".$request_uri[0]."'");
        // $id = mysql_result("SELECT user_Id FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name='".$request_uri[0]."'");
        // var_dump($id,0);die;

        // print_r($id);die;

         if ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
         {
                // If, there is a result, then we should modify server data
                // Below line means, we told CodeIgniter to load
                // 'User' controller on 'index', 'info' or any valid connection/method and we send 'id' parameter
                //$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/user';
            $id = mysql_result($res,0);
                //print_r($id);die;
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/user?id='.$id;
                //var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);die;

         }
         mysql_free_result($res);
    }

}
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Are you in the shared hosting? can you http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=Codeigniter+redirect+not+working check some of there, and also if you can read server error log it will help you too

Comment: what do you mean by `not working` please specify any error or its behavior.

Comment: It gives 404 error "The page you requested was not found."

Comment: I think problem is with the way you define hook use:
$hook['pre_system'][] => array(
                        'class'    => 'Userlookup',
                        'function' => 'check_uri',
                        'filename' => 'Userlookup.php',
                        'filepath' => 'hooks',
                        'params'   => NULL,
                ),
);

Comment: I think you should concentrate on your htaccess and routing to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have created the URL as I wanted such as example.com/username. Here I am posting it as a help for others.

[For more](http://daparky.com/codeigniter-vanity-username-personalised-urls/)

I used standard MVC

This type of vanity URL involve URI routing, So add below code for your "application/config/routes.php"

```
if($handle = opendir(APPPATH.'/controllers'))
{
    while(false !== ($controller = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if($controller != '.' && $controller != '..' && strstr($controller, '.') == '.php')
                {
                    $route[strstr($controller, '.', true)] = strstr($controller, '.', true);
                    $route[strstr($controller, '.', true).'/(:any)'] = strstr($controller, '.', true).'/$1';
                }
        }
    closedir($handle);
}

// these are the /username routes
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'controller/index/$1';
```

Then in your controller write you can get the username from GET.

```
function index($username = '')
{
    echo $username;
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you have requested, You don't need a hook nor an htaccess or event messing with the routes file.

Since you are keeping the controller name in the url, /users/[username] All you need is to define the catch-all method which is offered by Codeigniter.

You'll need something like this in your 'Users.php' controller:

```
public function _remap ($method, $params = array() ){
    if( method_exists($this, $method) ) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }else{
        $Username = $method;
        $data['User'] = $this->users_model->get_by_username($Username);
        $this->load->view('users/profile', $data);
    }
}
```